# How do I know when my docker mysql container is up and mysql is ready for taking queries?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, docker

I am deploying a few different docker containers, mysql being the first one. I want to run scripts as soon as database is up and proceed to building other containers. The script has been failing because it was trying to run when the entrypoint script, which sets up mysql (from [this official mysql container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)), was still running.

```
sudo docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MY_ROOT_PASS -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
[..] wait for mysql to be ready [..]
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root --password=MY_ROOT_PASS < MY_SQL_SCRIPT.sql
```

Is there a way to wait for a signal of an entrypoiny mysql setup script finishing inside the docker container? Bash sleep seems like a suboptimal solution.

EDIT: Went for a bash script like this. Not the most elegant and kinda brute force but works like a charm. Maybe someone will find that useful.

```
OUTPUT="Can't connect"
while [[ $OUTPUT == *"Can't connect"* ]]
do
    OUTPUT=$(mysql -h $APP_IP -P :$APP_PORT -u yyy --password=xxx <       ./my_script.sql 2>&1)
done
```

Comment: add a bash loop to check mysql service status ? I think that is as good as it can get.

Comment: Thanks @fabrizioM. I went with this approach.

Comment: this question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42757250/1313562).

Answer (score 91):

You can install mysql-client package and use mysqladmin to ping target server. Useful when working with multiple docker container. Combine with sleep and create a simple wait-loop:

```
while ! mysqladmin ping -h"$DB_HOST" --silent; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This is a beautiful thing. Works great for a Docker healthcheck, too: `docker run --health-cmd='mysqladmin ping --silent' -d mysql`

Comment: To wait unit container is healthy I used script `while [ $(docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health.Status }}" <container-name>) != "\"healthy\"" ]; do printf "."; sleep 1; done`

Comment: This does not work here; `mysqladmin ping` succeeds before I can actually use the database - I guess the container is still running is initialization `.sql` scripts.

Comment: I didn't have mysqladmin installed in docker image, however, wget also did the job: 
`while !  wget mysql:3306; do sleep 1 done`

Comment: If you try it on localhost and it doesn't work, try "127.0.0.1". When "localhost" is used, mysqladmin is trying to connect using a socket instead over the default TCP-port 3306.

Answer (score 51):

This little bash loop waits for mysql to be open, shouldn't require any extra packages to be installed:

```
until nc -z -v -w30 $CFG_MYSQL_HOST 3306
do
  echo "Waiting for database connection..."
  # wait for 5 seconds before check again
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Nice one. I used it as a 1 liner: until nc -z $CFG_MYSQL_HOST 3306; do sleep 1; echo "Waiting for DB to come up..."; done

Comment: Just because the port is available does not mean the server is ready to accept connections. `mysqladmin ping` is the correct answer here.

Comment: usually containers are as minimal as possible and mysql is not available. @QuolonelQuestions you may be right for some rare cases. The nc solution is precised enough even for a predictable docker environment. I vote for the lightweight nc.

Comment: The linux image I used did not have `nc`, so I had to install it via my Dockerfile: `RUN yum -y update && yum -y install nc` - apart from that, this was lightweight and worked.

Answer (score 44):

This was more or less mentioned in comments to other answers, but I think it deserves its own entry.

First of all you can run your container in the following manner:

```
docker run --name mysql --health-cmd='mysqladmin ping --silent' -d mysql
```

There is also an [equivalent](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) in the Dockerfile.

With that command your `docker ps` and `docker inspect` will show you health status of your container. For mysql in particular this method has the advantage of `mysqladmin` being available *inside the container*, so you do not need to install it on the docker host.

Then you can simply loop in a bash script to wait on the status to become healthy. The following bash script is created by [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/950430/dennis).

```
function getContainerHealth {
  docker inspect --format "{{.State.Health.Status}}" $1
}

function waitContainer {
  while STATUS=$(getContainerHealth $1); [ $STATUS != "healthy" ]; do 
    if [ $STATUS == "unhealthy" ]; then
      echo "Failed!"
      exit -1
    fi
    printf .
    lf=$'\n'
    sleep 1
  done
  printf "$lf"
}
```

Now you can do this in your script:

```
waitContainer mysql
```

and your script will wait until the container is up and running. The script will exit if the container becomes unhealthy, which is possible, if for example docker host is out of memory, so that the mysql cannot allocate enough of it for itself.

Comment: I found this to be the best approach as it depends only on Docker and should hence have less cross-platform issues. Only thing I encountered is that the image entrypoint spins up mysqlserver twice - once bare, and once initialized. `mysqladmin ping` catches the first spin up as well, which is likely what you don't want. In my case, running a dummy query with the schema you expect to be there worked best, i.e. change health command to be `mysql -u root -e "use your_schema;"`.

Comment: This works if you have a `healthcheck` for your container.  But the `.State.Health.Status` doesn't exist if you don't.  You might have to settle for `.State.Status` instead; but that says `running` too soon for this OP's needs.

Comment: @JesseChisholm huh? What do you think `--health-cmd` is for?

Comment: you can use `healthcheck` also with docker-compose
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck

Comment: Doesn't this require docker to be installed/accessible from inside your container? Or are you running this outside a container?

Comment: @stefan2718 depends on what you are trying to achieve. For the question and the solution it is assumed that you are running the docker command outside a container on a system with docker where the container in question is running.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh fair enough. I was trying to add this to my docker-compose setup, having my server container wait until my mysql container was ready, even when started at the same time. So the waiting would be done inside the container. I ended up adding the `wait-on` NPM package and using that.

Answer (score 20):

Some times the problem with the port is that the port could be *open*, but the database is not ready yet.

Other solutions require that you have installed the *mysql* o a *mysql client* in your host machine, but really you already have it inside the Docker container, so I prefer to use something like this:

Option 1:

```bash
while ! docker exec mysql mysqladmin --user=root --password=pass --host "127.0.0.1" ping --silent &> /dev/null ; do
    echo "Waiting for database connection..."
     sleep 2
done
```

Option 2 (from @VinGarcia):

```bash
while ! docker exec container_name mysql --user=root --password=pass -e "status" &> /dev/null ; do
    echo "Waiting for database connection..."
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: This seems the best and shortest option, however just pinging was not working for me, it still wasn't ready afterwards so I used the command: `mysql -u root -proot -e 'status' &> /dev/null` instead of `mysqladmin ping`

Comment: Option 2 is best to me!

Answer (score 18):

I've found that using the `mysqladmin ping` approach isn't always reliable, especially if you're bringing up a new DB. In that case, even if you're able to ping the server, you might be unable to connect if the user/privilege tables are still being initialized. Instead I do something like the following:

```
while ! docker exec db-container mysql --user=foo --password=bar -e "SELECT 1" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    sleep 1
done
```

So far I haven't encountered any problems with this method. I see that something similar was suggested by VinGarcia in a comment to one of the `mysqladmin ping` answers.

Comment: When and/or how should a script like this be executed? In the Dockerfile? I don't understand...

Answer (score 12):

One liner using curl, found on all linux distributions:

```
while ! curl -o - db-host:3306; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: This is the best solution by far. I would like to add that the container needs to have acces to curl. `RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y`

Comment: This method was working great for me in scripts until I upgraded to MacOS Monterey (I think). Sadly now it seems not to work

Comment: curl is not allowed from `docker` mysql and mariabdb. getting this error: 
`curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`

Comment: this one-liner works better in makefiles.

`while ! docker exec -it docker-container mysql --user=$(DB_USER) --password=$(DB_PASSWORD) -e "SELECT 1" >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 10):

The following health-check works for all my mysql containers:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7.16
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysql --database=$$MYSQL_DATABASE --password=$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --execute="SELECT count(table_name) > 0 FROM information_schema.tables;" --skip-column-names -B']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 4
    extends:
        file: docker-compose-common-config.yml
        service: common_service
```

Answer (score 7):

So I am not sure if any one has posted this. It doesn't look like any one has, so... there is a command in mysqladmin that features a wait, it handles testing of the connection, then retries internally and returns a success upon completion.

```sh
sudo docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MY_ROOT_PASS -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=MY_ROOT_PASS --wait=30 && mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root --password=MY_ROOT_PASS < MY_SQL_SCRIPT.sql
```

The important piece is `mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=MY_ROOT_PASS --wait=30 -v` with the `--wait` being the flag to wait until the connection is successful and the number being the amount of attempts to retry.

Ideally you would run that command from inside the docker container, but I didn't want to modify the original posters command too much.

When used in my make file for initialization

```
db.initialize: db.wait db.initialize


db.wait:
  docker-compose exec -T db mysqladmin ping -u $(DATABASE_USERNAME) -p$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) --wait=30 --silent

db.initialize:
  docker-compose exec -T db mysql -u $(DATABASE_USERNAME) -p$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) $(DATABASE_NAME) < dev/sql/base_instance.sql
```

Comment: Most elegant solution IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when my Django container tried to connect the mysql container just after it started. I solved it using the vishnubob's [wait-for.it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) script. Its a shell script which waits for an IP and a host to be ready before continuing. Here is the example I use for my applicaction.

```
./wait-for-it.sh \
    -h $(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME) \
    -p 3306 \
    -t 90
```

In that script I'm asking to the mysql container to wait maximum 90 seconds (it will run normally when ready) in the port 3306 (default mysql port) and the host asigned by docker for my MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME. The script have more variables but for mw worked with these three.

Answer (score 2):

If the docker container waiting for a mysql container is based on a **python image (for instance for a Django application)**, you can use the code below.

Advantages are:

- It's not based on [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh), which does wait for the IP and port of mysql to be ready, but this doesn't automatically mean also that the mysql initialization has finished.
- It's not a shell script based on a mysql or mysqladmin executable that must be present in your container: since your container is based on a python image, this would require installing mysql on top of that image. With the below solution, you use the technology that is already present in the container: pure python.

Code:

```
import time

import pymysql


def database_not_ready_yet(error, checking_interval_seconds):
    print('Database initialization has not yet finished. Retrying over {0} second(s). The encountered error was: {1}.'
          .format(checking_interval_seconds,
                  repr(error)))
    time.sleep(checking_interval_seconds)


def wait_for_database(host, port, db, user, password, checking_interval_seconds):
    """
    Wait until the database is ready to handle connections.

    This is necessary to ensure that the application docker container
    only starts working after the MySQL database container has finished initializing.

    More info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on .
    """
    print('Waiting until the database is ready to handle connections....')
    database_ready = False
    while not database_ready:
        db_connection = None
        try:
            db_connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                            port=port,
                                            db=db,
                                            user=user,
                                            password=password,
                                            charset='utf8mb4',
                                            connect_timeout=5)
            print('Database connection made.')
            db_connection.ping()
            print('Database ping successful.')
            database_ready = True
            print('The database is ready for handling incoming connections.')
        except pymysql.err.OperationalError as err:
            database_not_ready_yet(err, checking_interval_seconds)
        except pymysql.err.MySQLError as err:
            database_not_ready_yet(err, checking_interval_seconds)
        except Exception as err:
            database_not_ready_yet(err, checking_interval_seconds)
        finally:
            if db_connection is not None and db_connection.open:
                db_connection.close()
```

Usage:

1. Add this code into a python file (`wait-for-mysql-db.py` for instance) inside your application's source code.
2. Write another python script (`startup.py` for instance) that first executes the above code, and afterwards starts up your application.
3. Make sure your application container's Dockerfile packs these two python scripts together with the application's source code into a Docker image.
4. In your docker-compose file, configure your application container with: `command: ["python3", "startup.py"]`.

Note that this solution is made for a MySQL database. You'll need to adapt it slightly for another database.

Comment: Re: Database ping successful

I think it really means "database server ping successful".   The documentation for ping says it's checking if the connection is successful.   It makes no difference what database you're connected to

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I incorporated [Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6199829/adam) solution into my docker-compose based project:

Created a bash file titled `db-ready.sh` in my `server` container folder (the contents of which are copied in to my container - `server`):

```
#!bin/bash

until nc -z -v -w30 $MYSQL_HOST 3306
do
  echo "Waiting a second until the database is receiving connections..."
  # wait for a second before checking again
  sleep 1
done
```

I can then run `docker-compose run server sh ./db-ready.sh && docker-compose run server yarn run migrate` to ensure that when I run my `migrate` task within my `server` container, I know the DB will be accepting connections.

I like this approach as the bash file is separate to any command I want to run. I could easily run the `db-ready.sh` before any other DB using task I run.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but let me update it since I spent a lot of time to figure it out.
for those who are using migration tools like `alembic`, `mysqladmin ping` will not work for you (especially if your db will be intialized with script on start).
`mysqladmin ping` will guarantee that the db is up ( `mysqld.sock`is up) **but it does not guarantee that the db is able to process requests**

**My recommandations is to use `mysqladmin status` instead . the command will check if db is up AND can process requests (it will run sql request to get uptime,threads ..)**

example of code that can be used:

```
        while ! mysqladmin status -h"$DB_HOST" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" -u"$DB_USER"; do
            sleep 1
        done
```

source:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html

Comment: I also spent too much figuing it out, this works perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I developed a new solution for this issue based on a new approach. All approaches I found rely on a script that tries over and over to connect to the database, or try to establish a TCP connection with the container. The full details can be found on the [waitdb](https://github.com/marcelopbarros/waitdb) repository, but, my solution is to rely on the retrieved log from the container. The script waits until the log fires the message **ready for connections**. The script can identify if the container is starting for the first time. In this case the script waits until the initial database script is executed and the database is restarted, waiting again for a new **ready for connections** message. I tested this solution on MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0.

The script itself (*wait_db.sh*):

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING_CONNECT="mysqld: ready for connections"

findString() {
    ($1 logs -f $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 2>&1 | grep -m $3 "$2" &) | grep -m $3 "$2" > /dev/null
}

echo "Waiting startup..."
findString $1 "$STRING_CONNECT" 1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7
$1 logs $2 $3 $4 $5 2>&1 | grep -q "Initializing database"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Almost there..."
    findString $1 "$STRING_CONNECT" 2 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7
fi
echo "Server is up!"
```

The script can be used in Docker Compose or in Docker itself. I hope the examples bellow make the the usage clear:

#### Example 01: Using with Docker Compose

```
SERVICE_NAME="mysql" && \
docker-compose up -d $SERVICE_NAME && \
./wait_db.sh docker-compose --no-color $SERVICE_NAME
```

#### Example 02: Using with Docker

```
CONTAINER_NAME="wait-db-test" && \
ISO_NOW=$(date -uIs) && \
  docker run --rm --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$ROOT_PASSWORD \
    -d mysql:5.7 && \
./wait_db.sh docker --since "$ISO_NOW" $CONTAINER_NAME
```

#### Example 3: A full example (the test-case)

A full example can be found [on the test case of the repository](https://github.com/marcelopbarros/waitdb/blob/master/test_wait_db.sh). This test-case will startup a new MySQL, create a dummy database, wait until everything is started and then fires a *select* to check if everything goes fine. After that it'll going restart the container and wait it to be started and then fires a new *select* to check if it's ready for connection.

Answer (score 1):

i can recommend you to use `/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root --execute "SHOW DATABASE;"` in healthcheck script instead of `mysqladmin ping`. This wait for real initialization and service is ready for client connection.

Example:

````
  docker run -d --name "test-mysql-client" -p 0.0.0.0:3306:3306 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --health-cmd="/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root --execute \"SHOW DATABASE;\"" --health-interval=1s --health-retries=60 --health-timeout=10s -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db  mysql:latest```
````

Answer (score 1):

Combining **flamemyst**‘s answer and **Nathan Arthur**'s comment, I believe this answer would be the most convenient one:

```sh
CONTAINER_MYSQL='' # name of the MySQL container
CONTAINER_DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
CONTAINER_DB_PORT=3306
MYSQL_USER='' # user name if there is, normally 'root'
MYSQL_PWD='' # password you set

is_mysql_alive() {
  docker exec -it ${CONTAINER_MYSQL} \
    mysqladmin ping \
      --user=${MYSQL_USER} \
      --password=${MYSQL_PWD} \
      --host=${CONTAINER_DB_HOST} \
      --port=${CONTAINER_DB_PORT} \
    > /dev/null
  returned_value=$?
  echo ${returned_value}
}

until [ "$(is_mysql_alive)" -eq 0 ]
do
  sleep 2
  echo "Waiting for MySQL to be ready..."
done

anything_else_to_do
```

Basically, it checks whether `mysqladmin` is alive in MySQL container, MySQL should be up if so.

Answer (score 1):

Building a bit on Mihai Crăiță excellent answer above, I added in the CURL option to enable 0.9 (which is disabled by default now) and to hide the output to reduce log "noise" during startup:

```sh
server="MyServerName"
echo "Waiting for MySQL at ${server}"
while ! curl --http0.9 -o - "${server}:3306" &> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh
docker-entrypoint.sh doesn't support merging customized .sql yet.

I think you can modify docker-entrypoint.sh to merge your sql so it can be executed once mysql instance is ready.

Answer (score 0):

On your `ENTRYPOINT` script, you have to check if you have a valid MySQL connection or not.

> This solution does not require you to install a MySQL Client on the container and while running the container with `php:7.0-fpm` running `nc` was not an option, because it had to be installed as well. Also, checking if the port is open does not necessarily mean that the service is running and exposed correctly. [[more of this]](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374)

So in this solution, I will show you how to run a PHP script to check if a MySQL Container is able to take connection. If you want to know why I think this is a better approach check my comment [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374#issuecomment-248205686).

File `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF > /tmp/wait_for_mysql.php
<?php
\$connected = false;
while(!\$connected) {
    try{
        \$dbh = new pdo( 
            'mysql:host=mysql:3306;dbname=db_name', 'db_user', 'db_pass',
            array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
        );
        \$connected = true;
    }
    catch(PDOException \$ex){
        error_log("Could not connect to MySQL");
        error_log(\$ex->getMessage());
        error_log("Waiting for MySQL Connection.");
        sleep(5);
    }
}
EOF
php /tmp/wait_for_mysql.php
# Rest of entry point bootstrapping
```

By running this, you are essentially blocking any bootstrapping logic of your container UNTIL you have a valid MySQL Connection.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code ;

export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=web;

export IS_DATA_CONTAINER_EXISTS=$(docker volume ls | grep ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_sqldata);

```
docker-compose up -d;
docker-compose ps;

export NETWORK_GATEWAY=$(docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_webserver1_con);
```