# Docker compose: possible to model lazy startup of dependent services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I posted this question originally on the [Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/application-modeling-question-and-any-way-to-control-service-name/2558), but didn't get any response there.

I'm wondering what the best way would be to model a set of services let's call them `db`, `web`, and `batch`. `db` is simply a running database server instance (think MySQL). `web` is a web application that needs to connect to the database. `batch` is a batch application that needs to connect to that same database (it can/will run in parallel with `web`). `db` needs to be running, for either `web` or `batch` to run. But `web` or `batch` can be run independently of each other (one or both can be running at the same time). If both are running at once, they need to be talking to the same database instance (so `db` is actually using `volumes_from` a separate data volume container). So if the use case was simpler (think just `db` and `web`, which always run together), then they would simply both be defined as services in the same compose file, with `web` having a link to `db`.

As far as I understand it, these can't all be defined in the same Docker compose configuration.  Instead, I would need three different configurations.  One for `db`, which is launched first, one for `web` (which uses `external_links` to find `db`), and a third for `batch` (which also uses `external_links` to find `db`).  Is that correct, or is there some mechanism available that I'm not considering?  Assuming a multi-configuration setup is needed, is there a way to "lazily" initialize the `db` composition if it's not running, when either the `web` or `batch` compositions are launched?

Answer (score 1):

If `web` has a link defined to `db` in a docker-compose file, `db` will always start first.

As far as I know, Docker will never know when the database will be up. It will be your `web` container's responsibility to properly start and retry until the base is up (with a timeout).

For your `batch` service, assuming that you don't want to start it everytime you start your `web` and `db` containers (using a `docker-compose up` or `run`), you can try extending your service. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) for more informations on this.

Answer (score -1):

Either you applications in the `web` and `batch` images known how to handle database down time and are able to wait for the db service to come up and auto-reconnect ; either you have to make a shell script that will be run when the docker container is started to wait for the db to be available before starting the app.

Depending on the docker images you are using for the `web` and `batch` services, you would have to override [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd), [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or both.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503412/how-do-i-know-when-my-docker-mysql-container-is-up-and-mysql-is-ready-for-taking) has examples of shell script which waits for a MySQL service to be up.

And [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/how-do-i-tell-a-script-to-wait-for-a-process-to-start-accepting-requests-on-a-po) are other technics for testing if a network port is opened.

Comment: That addresses the question of how to make other apps correctly depend on the database being up.  But I'm still unclear on whether Docker, or Docker Compose, has a built in facility to *start the database itself* the moment any of the dependent services are started (which would obviously need to handle a state that the DB is not yet running).

Comment: Docker and docker-compose both have no clue about the things that run inside the containers. And it is not their business to know that

Comment: That is correct.  However, docker-compose allows you to externally define those dependencies (via `links`, `external_links`, and the like).  My question was intended in that context of modeling.

Comment: if you are to make different docker-compose config files, then you would either have to manually launch the db one and wait for it to be up, then manually launch the others. Or, you would have to come up with some sort of shell script to do the same thing for you.

It does not change the problem: some way or the other one has to wait for the db to be up