# grails/mysql with docker compose

Tags: java, grails, jdbc, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a grails app in docker and keep running in some mysql connection problems. I can't figure out where the problem is.

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "2"
   services:
      db:
       image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: always
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root2017
          MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
          MYSQL_USER: Dbuser
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: passw
 grails:
   depends_on:
     - db
   ports:
     - "9001:9001"
   restart: always
   environment:
     DB_HOST: db:3306
     DB_PASSWORD: passw
volumes:
    db_data:
```

The grails app does not start with the following error:

ERROR 18:08:05 org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
grails_1  | com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know when my docker mysql container is up and mysql is ready for taking queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503412/how-do-i-know-when-my-docker-mysql-container-is-up-and-mysql-is-ready-for-taking)

Comment: This is likely caused by the database not being available at the point where your Java app starts. Please take a look at the linked question, it contains several solutions for waiting for the database to be up. I use https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was that i changed passwords in the compose file, since its mounted to the volume I had to delete the volume in order to set the new passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your datasource to point to `"jdbc:mysql://db:3306/dbname"`

You can do this with external config file for production env.
Or you can read the values for host and db name from system environments.

See [Deploying grails application war to tomcat with docker and docker compose](http://nimavat.me/blog/deploy-grails-application-war-to-tomcat-docker-container)