# How to make a service wait for another to be ready?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose, flyway, testcontainers

I am using flyway with a mysql db. I am using them as services in a docker-compose and then using this in [testcontainer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcontainers)'s DockerComposeEnvironment. The problem is that even though I have added the `depends_on` key in 'flyway' service for the MySQL 'db', testcontainer starts flyway first and this results in the migrations not being applied.

I want to know if there is a method by which we can make flyway container run only when the db container is ready?

I am using this piece of code to initialize my test docker-compose environment (`test_mysql` and `flyway_c` are the names of the containers of the services):

```
const environment = await new DockerComposeEnvironment(composeFilePath, composeFile)
        .withWaitStrategy('test_mysql', Wait.forLogMessage(`ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port:`))
        .withWaitStrategy('flyway_c', Wait.forLogMessage(`Successfully applied`))
        .withStartupTimeout(120000)
        .up();
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
      - '33060:33060'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    container_name: test_mysql
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    command: -url=jdbc:mysql://db -schemas=test_db -user=root -password=pass -connectRetries=100 migrate
    volumes:
      - .:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: flyway_c
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

This problem is not caused by the docker-compose. In other words, the service `flyway` does wait for `db` if they are run as `docker-compose up` but they fail when running inside the *testcontainers* npm library. So, [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) doesn't really resolve this.

I have added the answer which I used to resolve this for me. Thanks!

Comment: You could create an `entrypoint.sh` for your `flyway` service and use this technique here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29793382/9835872

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Comment: Thanks both of you. Those were very helpful links and helped me debug as to what was going wrong. I went ahead without overwriting the endpoint. However, the real problem turned out to be something else. It was the timeout. Increasing it to 150000 allowed the tests to run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long session of logging and debugging, the issue seems to be the timeout. The 120000ms I specified turned out to be insufficient for the MySQL container to fire up. Increasing the timeout to say 150000ms does the trick.